# reverse a string using pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reverse

I have to admit, i have no idea how to use pointers, but I tried non the less. the problem with my program is that it shows the string in reverse, except for what was the first letter being missing and the entire string is moved one space forward with the first element being blank.
for example it show " olle" when typing "hello".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string reverse(string word);

int main()
{
char Cstring[50];
cout<<"enter a word: ";
cin>>Cstring;
string results = reverse(Cstring);
cout <<results;
}

string reverse(string word)
{
    char *front;
    char *rear;
    for (int i=0;i< (word.length()/2);i++)
    {
            front[0]=word[i];
            rear[0]=word[word.length()-i];
            word[i]=*rear;
            word[word.length()-i]=*front;
    }
    return word;
}
```

The new code works perfectly. changed the strings to cstrings. the question technicaly asked for cstrings but i find strings easier so i work with strings then make the necesary changes to make it c string. figured out ho to initialize the rear and front as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

string reverse(char word[20]);

int main()
{
char Cstring[20];
cout<<"enter a word: ";
cin>>Cstring;
string results = reverse(Cstring);
cout <<results;
}

string reverse(char word[20])
{
    char a='a';
    char b='b';
    char *front=&a;
    char *rear=&b;
    for (int i=0;i< (strlen(word)/2);i++)
    {
            front[0]=word[i];
            rear[0]=word[strlen(word)-1-i];
            word[i]=*rear;
            word[strlen(word)-1-i]=*front;
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that your code works by sheer luck. You're using (dereferencing) two `char` pointers that you haven't initialized, `front` and `rear`.

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for `front` and `rear`, so you're invoking undefined behaviour when using `front[0]` and `rear[0]`. Apart from that, the last index of the word is `word[word.length() - 1]` and you should use `word[word.length() - 1 - i]`.

Comment: so what do i initialize them to, any old character or something specific, as I have said I am quite new to pointers.

Comment: "i have no idea how to use pointers" — good, this here planet needs less pointers and more sane, human-readable code. Please help the world stamp out pointers by refusing to learn them.

Comment: ok. i see, i think. so basicly i am trying t access a non existant element in word.

Comment: its part of my course work. i actually have no idea what the point of pointers are.

Comment: no it gives me hleh and still has the extra blank spot at the start of the new string. that is if i change word[word.length() - i] to word[word.length() - 1 - i]

Comment: it works now. I forgot to change all the word[word.length() - i] to word[word.length() - 1 - i]. ok thanks.

Comment: although i still haven't initialized the rear and front. exactly how do i do that. my notes does not say.

Comment: the new code, changed to cstring due to question requirement.

Answer (score 5):

```
char *front;
char *rear;
```

then later

```
front[0]=word[i];
rear[0]=word[strlen(word)-1-i];
```

Not good. Dereferencing uninitialized pointers invokes undefined behavior.

Apart from that, your code is overly complicated, it calls `strlen()` during each iteration (and even multiple times), which is superfluous, and the swap logic is also unnecessarily complex. Try using two pointers instead and your code will be much cleaner:

```
void rev_string(char *str)
{
    char *p = str, *s = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while (p < s) {
        char tmp = *p;
        *p++ = *s;
        *s-- = tmp;
    }
}
```

The thing is, however, that in C++ there's rarely a good reason for using raw pointers. How about using `std::reverse()` instead?

```
string s = "foobar";
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Comment: Yay for the correct short C-style code.  The uninitialized `front` and `rear` were fixed in the second edition in the question, but that is ... interesting code, shall we say.  And the misuse of `strlen()` is pretty blatant too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Yap, and I didn't even want to mention the unreadable spaceless coding style, which is not strictly a technical error, but still makes code look very unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

```
inline void swap(char* a, char* b)
{
    char tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

inline void reverse_string(char* pstart, char* pend)
{
    while(pstart < pend)
    {
        swap(pstart++, pend--);
    }

}

int main()
{
    char pstring[] = "asfasd Lucy Beverman";
    auto pstart = std::begin(pstring);
    auto pend = std::end(pstring);
    pend -= 2; // end points 1 past the null character, so have to go back 2
    std::cout << pstring << std::endl;        
    reverse_string(pstart, pend);
    std::cout << pstring << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

string reverse(char word[20]);

int main()
{
char Cstring[20];
cout<<"enter a word: ";
cin>>Cstring;
string results = reverse(Cstring);
cout <<results;
}

string reverse(char word[20])
{
    char a='a';
    char b='b';
    char *front=&a; 
    char *rear=&b;
    for (int i=0;i< (strlen(word)/2);i++)
    {
            *front=word[i];
            *rear=word[strlen(word)-1-i];
            word[i]=*rear;
            word[strlen(word)-1-i]=*front;
    }
    return word;
}
```

it successfully works on my system ,i.e. on **emacs+gcc** on **windows 7**

Comment: As far as I can see from the edit records, user2420395 created his answer (in an edit to the question) on 2013-06-19 20:57; you created your answer on 2013-06-20 05:10, some 8 hours later.  The only difference between what he wrote and what you wrote is `front[0]` vs `*front` and `rear[0]` vs `*rear`.  This does not change the function of the code; only the nomenclature is different. I'm not sure why you'd expect any credit for it, therefore. It isn't even a very good algorithm. There are far too many uses of `strlen()` to be sensible. The best solution using C pointers is far simpler.

Comment: It means that i may not have seen the edit at that time or i could not have paid attention to it, at that time there were important problems as you can see, OP had not initialized front and rear variables at that time,and as you can see mine was the only answer so i thought accepting it won't do any harm but now other "better" answer is available , i won't expect any credit whatsoever.It can't be undermined that new users here crave for "reputation" so that was  my cause.If you feel mine is not very good answer,you are good enough to down vote it!

Answer (score -1):

Taken from C How To Program Deitel & Deitel 8th edition:

```
void reverse(const char * const sPtr)
{
    if (sPtr[0] == '\0')
        return;
    else
        reverse(&sPtr[1]);
        putchar(sPtr[0]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, now you're just printing the string backwards in a non-C++ way. Once again, the function is only useful (to other C++ code) if it returns something via reference, pointer, etc. Notice that the OP's `reverse` function returns a `string`. Some other answers modify the input string.